# Javascript Style Transform Syntax (for an image slider/carousel)

Tags: javascript, carousel

I was following a YouTube tutorial for a Javascript Image Slider, and I came across this line of code that I'd like to better understand so that I can effectively modify it to suit my website's needs.

Here's the line:

carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';

1. carouselSlide is what contains all of the images in the image slider.
2. size is the width of a single image (they are all the same width).
3. counter increases each time a button is pressed.

The main source of my confusion is how everything is concatenated. I don't quite understand why the two single quotes are necessary inside of the translateX argument (and why they're positioned where they are), nor do I understand why the plusses are necessary.

Could someone help me understand the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

`'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)'` is constructing a string using fixed text and the values from the size and counter variables.  Quotes are added around the fixed text and `+` is required to add bits of the string together into a single string.

`'translateX('` - a fixed string

`+` - a concatenator

`(-size * counter)` - calculate a value from variables

`+` - a concatenator

`'px)'` - a fixed string

Thus, once the calculation has been done, and if we assume that equated to 100:

`'translateX(' + 100 + 'px)'`

which is joined together to get:

`'translateX(100px)'`

It may look confusing because `+` is usually used for addition - but, it is also be used to concatenate strings.